# Melhoria desempenho Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Estou em desenvolvimento de uma aplicação em Swing utilizando o Hibernate, porém ainda não conheço todos os macetes que a ferramenta possui e o desenvolvimento utilizado-a esta me proporcionando um belo conhecimento, porém me deparei com um situação que pesquisei na internet e em alguns livros muita gente faz cada um de cada jeito, mas gostaria de saber o que é usado, o mais correto e o de melhor desempenho pois é onde esta perdendo muito.

Vamos lá, no ato de realizar uma comunicação entre sistema e banco de dados, mesmo que seja uma simples consulta de um único nome, percebo que o Hibernate ao chamar o `persistence.xml` mapeia todo o meu banco de dados causando uma lentidão nestes momentos, lembrando que criei uma classe chamada `ConexaoJPA.java` que faz a conexão utilizando o `persistence.xml` que tem somente uma única conexão no persistence-unit.

Será que devo criar varias conexões dentro do `persistence.xml` cada uma para cada tabela do banco? Acho que isso seria muito inútil ter que ficar recriando muitas conexões sendo que poderia usar uma só e quando eu chamar tal modelo ele mapeasse a tabela correta e somente a tabela que necessito.

Alguém saberia me dizer se existe uma forma de melhorar o desempenho e manter tudo centralizado em uma conexão só?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clayton, faltam-lhe alguns conceitos sobre como funciona o Hibernate. Realmente há várias fontes que ensinam diferente e entendo que isso torna a coisa muito confusa para quem está começando. Mas, justamente por isso, procure ler algum livro ou fonte mais confiável sobre o assunto para entender os conceitos e então poder julgar por si mesmo qual é a melhor forma de resolver o seu problema.

## Persistence.xml

O primeiro ponto importante para você entender é sobre o `persistence.xml`.

Nele você pode configurar os dados de conexão e as classes (entidades) que mapeiam tabelas do banco de dados.

Este é um arquivo de configuração e não diz respeito diretamente a quantas conexões ou tabelas você tem no banco de dados.

Enfim, você não precisa se preocupar muito este arquivo nesse sentido.

## Conexões

O Hibernate ou qualquer outra implementação do JPA não vai abrir uma conexão para cada tabela ou entidade, nem vai necessariamente abrir uma conexão cada vez que você vai ler ou gravar algo do banco. Uma coisa não tem nada a ver com a outra.

Se a sua aplicação é Swing, provavelmente você vai querer apenas uma única conexão aberta com o banco de dados e reusá-la sempre que necessário.

Se fosse uma aplicação web, você poderia ter um *pool* de conexões para otimizar o desempenho da aplicação.

## `EntityManagerFactory` e `EntityManager`

Para usar Hibernate com a API do JPA você vai usar as classes `EntityManagerFactory` e `EntityManager`.

### `EntityManagerFactory`

O `EntityManagerFactory` é quem vai carregar as configurações do `persistence.xml`. A criação de uma instância dessa classe é custosa e lenta, já que o Hibernate irá inicializar várias coisas e pode fazer leituras e alterações no banco de dados, dependendo de sua configuração.

A recomendação é criar o `EntityManagerFactory` uma única vez por banco de dados e depois reusá-lo para criar o `EntityManager` sempre que for necessário acessar o banco de dados.

### `EntityManager`

O `EntityManager` é mais ou menos o equivalente a uma conexão do banco de dados. Com ele você vai executar as operações necessários com o JPA no banco de dados.

Numa aplicação *desktop* você pode criar apenas uma instância do `EntityManager` e reusar sempre que necessário, desde que não haja concorrência pois ele não é *thread-safe*. No caso de várias *threads* seria recomendável criar um `EntityManager` para cada uma delas.

## Considerações

Espero ter conseguido dar uma breve introdução ao assunto.

E, para finalizar, sugiro que você use um framework como o [Spring](http://spring.io/) para gerenciar seus "componentes" (classes), a conexão com o banco de dados e a injeção de dependência do `EntityManager`.

Mesmo em aplicativos que executam localmente, um framework pode ajudar você a não reinventar a roda e acabar com mais problemas por falta de experiência.

Fiz uma breve pesquisa e encontrei um projeto aberto com as tecnologias mencionadas. Ele pode servir como base para você. Para acessá-lo, [clique aqui](http://www.yaw.com.br/open/projetos/swing-spring-jpa-crud/).